# Function array items are not updating the global array items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am cycling through the items in the array and for each item (string) I update the string by adding ' juice!'. Shouldn't this change each string by having the new string added to it?

```
var fruits = ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Tomato', 'Strawberry']

fruits.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item += ' juice!';
  console.log(item);
})

console.log(fruits);
```

Output:

```
Orange juice!
Apple juice!
Tomato juice!
Strawberry juice!
[ 'Orange', 'Apple', 'Tomato', 'Strawberry' ]
```

Expected output:

```
Orange juice!
Apple juice!
Tomato juice!
Strawberry juice!
[ 'Orange juice!', 'Apple juice!', 'Tomato juice!', 'Strawberry juice!' ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable. `+=`ing to a variable name which references a string will create an *entirely new string* and assign the new string to *that variable name*, and that variable name only.

If another variable held a reference to the original string, it will not be changed. Here, an `item` is being reassigned, but the `fruits` array remains unchanged, because you never assign to `fruits[0]` or `fruits[1]` etc.

To create a new array, either reassign like `fruits[index] = item` at the end, or use `.map`:

```js
var fruits = ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Tomato', 'Strawberry']

const newFruits = fruits.map(function(item, index) {
  item += ' juice!';
  console.log(item);
  return item;
})

console.log(newFruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `const` and `.map()`

```js
const fruits = ['Orange', 'Apple', 'Tomato', 'Strawberry']
const fruitJuice = fruits.map(fruit => (fruit.concat(' juice!')))
console.log(fruitJuice)
```